# How to center a window on the screen in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, centering

I'm trying to center a tkinter window. I know I can programatically get the size of the window and the size of the screen and use that to set the geometry, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to center the window on the screen.

Comment: app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % app.winfo_pathname(app.winfo_id())) doesn't work on KDE Plasma, I saw this code many time but never worked fine, the longer version is much better and work everytime on windows or linux.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can try to use the methods `winfo_screenwidth` and `winfo_screenheight`, which return respectively the width and height (in pixels) of your `Tk` instance (window), and with some basic math you can center your window:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PyQt4 import QtGui    # or PySide

def center(toplevel):
    toplevel.update_idletasks()

    # Tkinter way to find the screen resolution
    # screen_width = toplevel.winfo_screenwidth()
    # screen_height = toplevel.winfo_screenheight()

    # PyQt way to find the screen resolution
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    screen_width = app.desktop().screenGeometry().width()
    screen_height = app.desktop().screenGeometry().height()

    size = tuple(int(_) for _ in toplevel.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
    x = screen_width/2 - size[0]/2
    y = screen_height/2 - size[1]/2

    toplevel.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
    toplevel.title("Centered!")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Not centered")

    win = tk.Toplevel(root)
    center(win)

    root.mainloop()
```

I am calling `update_idletasks` method before retrieving the width and the height of the window in order to ensure that the values returned are accurate.

*Tkinter* doesn't see if there are 2 or more monitors extended horizontal or vertical. So, you 'll get the total resolution of all screens together and your window will end-up somewhere in the middle of the screens.

*PyQt* from the other hand, doesn't see multi-monitors environment either, but it will get only the resolution of the Top-Left monitor (Imagine 4 monitors, 2 up and 2 down making a square). So, it does the work by putting the window on center of that screen. If you don't want to use both, *PyQt* and *Tkinter*, maybe it would be better to go with PyQt from start.

Comment: "not most powerful" is a bit subjective. It has as much "power" as other toolkits (depending on your definition of "power"), it just doesn't do as much hand-holding. It's the difference between building a house with pre-made walls (some other toolkits) or building it from a pile of lumber (Tk). You can pretty much do anything in Tkinter that you can do in other toolkits, you just have to sometimes work a little for it.

Comment: @Bryan - that's precisely what I mean by power. Sure you can get across the United States in a Yugo (maybe) and a Ferrari, but one of them can get you there a lot faster. Of course they both have the power to interact with the user in certain ways, but Tkinter doesn't have the power to let you write larger programs in less lines (and with less effort). Of course, smaller programs are actually easier in Tkinter because you don't have to worry about the same overhead for widgets as other toolkits, and that's what I love Tkinter for - writing smaller programs. @psicopoo, you're welcome!

Comment: When I use this method, the window _jumps_ to center and is not appeared in the center at first. Why it is so?

Comment: @mohammad.k because tkinter gets to draw the window before the call happens. There are some techniques that you could probably use to get around that I think, such as withdrawing the window first.

Comment: @WayneWerner If I withdraw the window, after deiconify nothing is shown but a tiny rectangle.

Comment: Do you re-size the window when it's de-iconified?

Comment: Good solution, but there is an issue. Functions `.winfo_screenwidth()` and `.winfo_screenheigth()` doesn't see if there are 2 or more monitors connected on PC horizontal or vertical. So, let's say that you have 2  monitors on PC extended horizontal, this will launch the "half left" window on the right edge of the left screen and "half right" window on the left edge of the right screen. Is there any way to get the pixels of the active monitor, the monitors number or if they are extended vertical or horizontal ??

Comment: Heads up: I've edited your answer so it no longer sets the window to a fixed size. Your original code prevented the window from resizing itself when widgets were added/removed/resized.

Comment: By using a totally different GUI toolkit, this adds an unreasonably large dependency and complication for packaging. Can anyone with a few years of experience in software distribution actually recommend this approach? I can't.

Comment: Sure, I wouldn't /recommend/ it - that's just silly. But if centering your window, cross platform, is a desire, you probably don't want tkinter

Comment: Glad to hear we are in agreement Wayne. Unfortunately, the example as provided by 3rd party editors uses this approach, which implies it's a reasonable solution.

Comment: Thanks!!
in my case I had to install `PyQt5` and `import QtWidgets` from it (instead of `from PyQt4 import QtGui`). I guess it's some kind of upgrade or update :)

Answer (score 100):

The simplest (but possibly inaccurate) method is to use [tk::PlaceWindow](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/tk.tcl#L72), which takes the [pathname](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/concepts.html) of a toplevel window as an argument. The main window's pathname is `.`

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

second_win = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
root.eval(f'tk::PlaceWindow {str(second_win)} center')

root.mainloop()
```

---

**The problem**

Simple solutions ignore the outermost frame with the title bar and the [menu bar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm), which leads to a slight offset from being truly centered.

**The solution**

```
import tkinter  # Python 3

def center(win):
    """
    centers a tkinter window
    :param win: the main window or Toplevel window to center
    """
    win.update_idletasks()
    width = win.winfo_width()
    frm_width = win.winfo_rootx() - win.winfo_x()
    win_width = width + 2 * frm_width
    height = win.winfo_height()
    titlebar_height = win.winfo_rooty() - win.winfo_y()
    win_height = height + titlebar_height + frm_width
    x = win.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - win_width // 2
    y = win.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - win_height // 2
    win.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
    win.deiconify()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
    menubar = tkinter.Menu(root)
    filemenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)
    frm = tkinter.Frame(root, bd=4, relief='raised')
    frm.pack(fill='x')
    lab = tkinter.Label(frm, text='Hello World!', bd=4, relief='sunken')
    lab.pack(ipadx=4, padx=4, ipady=4, pady=4, fill='both')
    center(root)
    root.attributes('-alpha', 1.0)
    root.mainloop()
```

With tkinter you always want to call the [`update_idletasks()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) method
directly before retrieving any geometry, to ensure that the values returned are accurate.

There are four methods that allow us to determine the outer-frame's dimensions.
`winfo_rootx()` will give us the window's top left x coordinate, **excluding** the outer-frame.
`winfo_x()` will give us the outer-frame's top left x coordinate.
Their difference is the outer-frame's width.

```
frm_width = win.winfo_rootx() - win.winfo_x()
win_width = win.winfo_width() + (2*frm_width)
```

The difference between `winfo_rooty()` and `winfo_y()` will be our title-bar / menu-bar's height.

```
titlebar_height = win.winfo_rooty() - win.winfo_y()
win_height = win.winfo_height() + (titlebar_height + frm_width)
```

You set the window's dimensions and the location with the [geometry method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method). The first half of the [geometry string](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html) is the window's width and height **excluding** the outer-frame,
and the second half is the outer-frame's top left x and y coordinates.

```
win.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}')
```

---

**You see the window move**

One way to prevent seeing the window move across the screen is to use
[`.attributes('-alpha', 0.0)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.attributes-method) to make the window fully transparent and then set it to `1.0` after the window has been centered. Using `withdraw()` or `iconify()` later followed by `deiconify()` doesn't seem to work well, for this purpose, on Windows 7. I use `deiconify()` as a trick to activate the window.

---

**Making it optional**

You might want to consider providing the user with an option to center the window, and not center by default; otherwise, your code can interfere with the window manager's functions. For example, xfwm4 has smart placement, which places windows side by side until the screen is full. It can also be set to center all windows, in which case you won't have the problem of seeing the window move (as addressed above).

---

**Multiple monitors**

If the multi-monitor scenario concerns you, then you can either look into the [screeninfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866046/1217270) project, or look into what you can accomplish with [Qt (PySide6)](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtGui/QScreen.html) or [GTK (PyGObject)](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gdk-3.0/classes/Display.html), and then use one of those toolkits instead of tkinter. Combining GUI toolkits results in an unreasonably large dependency.

Comment: It looks like the center function doesn't work in raw X11 over SSH, on Windows via Xming.  Seems to adhere to Window's standard form placement, starting from the top-left.  Geometry output looks correct, but it's possible some kind of interaction with Xming isn't working?

Comment: the -alpha trick doesn't seem to work in Linux. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Your code sets the window to a fixed size. The window will not automatically resize itself when widgets are added/removed/resized. It would be better to set only the window's position and leave its size alone.

Comment: Aran-Fey, i have implemented this code into my Method, that creates a Toplevel window, which also includes a Label with an Image that gets resized. If you call this method AFTER your call the resizing methods, it will place the window with the resized images in the center, so it does work for me, the trick just was to call the method after the resizing.

Answer (score 45):

## This answer is better for understanding beginner

#

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()  # Creating instance of Tk class
win.title("Centering windows")
win.resizable(False, False)  # This code helps to disable windows from resizing

window_height = 500
window_width = 900

screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = win.winfo_screenheight()

x_cordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))

win.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have a problem with two screens, the with is primary screen + secondary screen. The window starts between two screens.

Answer (score 31):

Tk provides a helper function that can do this as [tk::PlaceWindow](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/tk.tcl#L72), but I don't believe it has been exposed as a wrapped method in Tkinter. You would center a widget using the following:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % app.winfo_pathname(app.winfo_id()))
app.mainloop()
```

This function should deal with multiple displays correctly as well. It also has options to center over another widget or relative to the pointer (used for placing popup menus), so that they don't fall off the screen.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not consider the outer frame with the title and close button; so it's still not fully centered (on Windows 7 at least). This is the short alternative to Wayne's answer. +1 for bringing this up though. Maybe we can get it upgraded by the Tk developers.

Comment: winfo_pathname fails on Python 3.5.1 (on Win10) with `_tkinter.TclError: window id "2885868" doesn't exist in this application`. I don't think I ever had this working on Python 3, but from your lower case import, I assume it worked for you? I was able to update the code by using winfo_toplevel instead: `app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % app.winfo_toplevel())`

Answer (score 24):

This works also in Python 3.x and centers the window on screen:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 13):

I have found a solution for the same question [on this site](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1167024#p1167024)

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Label
root = Tk()
Label(root, text="Hello world").pack()

# Apparently a common hack to get the window size. Temporarily hide the
# window to avoid update_idletasks() drawing the window in the wrong
# position.
root.withdraw()
root.update_idletasks()  # Update "requested size" from geometry manager

x = (root.winfo_screenwidth() - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
y = (root.winfo_screenheight() - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2
root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

# This seems to draw the window frame immediately, so only call deiconify()
# after setting correct window position
root.deiconify()
root.mainloop()
```

sure, I changed it correspondingly to my purposes, it works.

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Centered!')

    w = 800
    h = 650

    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple one without the need of external modules:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

WIDTH = 300
HEIGHT = 250

x = int((root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (WIDTH / 2))
y = int((root.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (HEIGHT / 2))

root.geometry(f'{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}+{x}+{y}')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

**CENTERING THE WINDOW IN PYTHON Tkinter**
This is the most easiest thing in tkinter because all we must know is the dimension of the window as well as the dimensions of the computer screen. I come up with the following code which can help someone somehow and i did add some comments so that they can follow up.

**code**

```
    #  create a window first
    root = Tk()
    # define window dimensions width and height
    window_width = 800
    window_height = 500
    # get the screen size of your computer [width and height using the root object as foolows]
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    # Get the window position from the top dynamically as well as position from left or right as follows
    position_top = int(screen_height/2 -window_height/2)
    position_right = int(screen_width / 2 - window_width/2)
    # this is the line that will center your window
    root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{position_right}+{position_top}')
    # initialise the window
    root.mainloop(0)
```

Comment: Good answer, +1, but I know easier things in tkinter :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use frame and expand option. Very simple. I want some buttons in the middle of screen. Resize window and button stay in the middle. This is my solution.

```
frame = Frame(parent_window)
Button(frame, text='button1', command=command_1).pack(fill=X)
Button(frame, text='button2', command=command_2).pack(fill=X)
Button(frame, text='button3', command=command_3).pack(fill=X)
frame.pack(anchor=CENTER, expand=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

# Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
print("Width",windowWidth,"Height",windowHeight)

# Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)

# Positions the window in the center of the page.
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

### Multi monitor solution (even complex geometries)

I used a combination of `tkinter` and `screeninfo` to be able to center windows on the currently active monitor in the case you have a root window and want to place a popup on the center of the screen the root window currently resides in.

In this example, `root` is the root window and `popup` is the popup to be placed in the center of the screen where the `root` is located.

This solutions also works if your screens are setup in a more complex way than next to each other, for example on top of each other.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from screeninfo import get_monitors

def place_popup(popup: tk.Toplevel, root: tk.Tk, width: int, height: int) -> None:
    """Places a new window in the middle of the selected screen"""
    monitor = get_monitor_from_coord(root.winfo_x(), root.winfo_y())
    popup.geometry(
        f"{width}x{height}+{(monitor.width - width) // 2 + monitor.x}+{(monitor.height - height) // 2+ monitor.y}")

def get_monitor_from_coord(x, y):
    """Find the active monitor from tkinter geometry coords"""
    monitors = get_monitors()

    for m in reversed(monitors):
        if m.x <= x <= m.width + m.x and m.y <= y <= m.height + m.y:
            return m
    return monitors[0]

...
place_popup(popup, root, width, height)
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is cross-platform, works for multiple monitors/screens (targets the active screen), and requires no other libraries than Tk. The root window will appear centered without any unwanted "flashing" or animations:

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_geometry(frame):
    geometry = frame.winfo_geometry()
    match = re.match(r'^(\d+)x(\d+)\+(\d+)\+(\d+)$', geometry)
    return [int(val) for val in match.group(*range(1, 5))]

def center_window(root):
    """Must be called after application is fully initialized
    so that the root window is the true final size."""
    # Avoid unwanted "flashing" by making window transparent until fully ready
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0)

    # Get dimensions of active screen/monitor using fullscreen trick; withdraw
    # window before making it fullscreen to preserve previous dimensions
    root.withdraw()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.update_idletasks()
    (screen_width, screen_height, *_) = get_geometry(root)
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', False)

    # Restore and get "natural" window dimensions
    root.deiconify()
    root.update_idletasks()
    (window_width, window_height, *_) = get_geometry(root)

    # Compute and set proper window center
    pos_x = round(screen_width / 2 - window_width / 2)
    pos_y = round(screen_height / 2 - window_height / 2)
    root.geometry(f'+{pos_x}+{pos_y}')
    root.update_idletasks()
    
    root.attributes('-alpha', 1)

# Usage:
root = tk.Tk()
center_window(root)
```

Note that at every point where window geometry is modified, `update_idletasks()` must be called to force the operation to occur synchronously/immediately. It uses Python 3 functionality but can easily be adapted to Python 2.x if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a possible solution:

```
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *

x=pyautogui.size()[0]
y=pyautogui.size()[1]

root=Tk()
root.geometry('300x200+'+str(int(x/2-150))+'+'+str(int(y/2-100))) 
# x/2 and y/2 fin the display center and -<a half of x root> and -<a half of #y root> #serve to center root

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is import the `get_monitors` function from `screeninfo`. Then set my preferred width and height of my window. Finally, I calculate the position and interpolate everything as a string for the `.geometry()` method's input.

```
from screeninfo import get_monitors
import tkinter as tk

# Set the size of my window to whatever I like
WIN_WIDTH = 350
WIN_HEIGHT = 250

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry.(f"{WIN_WIDTH}x{WIN_HEIGHT}+{(get_monitors()[0].width - WIN_WIDTH)//2}+{(get_monitors()[0].height - WIN_HEIGHT)//2}")
```