# how to make Tkinter windows appear when opened rather than start minimized?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I open Tkinter windows (such as entry, text...) and make them appear on the screen when they are opened rather than start minimized ?
I don't really know how to start...  I have some windows but they are opened minimized. I searched on the internet, but found nothing that may be relevant. how can I do it ?
using python on windows (both Python 3 and Python 2)
thanks for the help in advance !

EDIT: the problem now as I mentioned in a comment here is that I have to force the window to be showed. But when I do so, the window does not start centered even if I use a function to center it **that worked before.**

code:

```
def center(toplevel):
    toplevel.update_idletasks()
    w = toplevel.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = toplevel.winfo_screenheight()
    size = tuple(int(_) for _ in toplevel.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
    x = w/2 - size[0]/2
    y = h/2 - size[1]/2
    toplevel.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + (x, y)))


def paste_func():
    global text_box
    text_box.insert(END, top.clipboard_get())
    button_pressed()


def button_pressed(x=0):
    # This function determines which button was pressed, and closes this menu/message box/etc...
    global pressed
    pressed = x
    destroy_top()


def destroy_top():
    # This function closes this menu/message box/etc...
    global top
    top.iconify()
    top.withdraw()
    top.quit()

def get_text():
    global pressed
    global top
    global text_box

    pressed = 0
    top = Tk()
    top.withdraw()
    top.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
    top.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
    top.config(height=0, width=0)
    top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: button_pressed(-1))

    text_box = Entry(top, width=50)
    text_box.focus_set()
    text_box.grid(row=0, column=0)
    but = Button(top, text='Enter', command=button_pressed)
    but.grid(row=0, column=1)
    paste = Button(top, text='Paste', command=paste_func)
    paste.grid(row=0, column=2)

    top.deiconify()
    text_box.focus_set()
    top.after(0, top.focus_force())
    center(top)
    top.mainloop()

    if pressed == -1:
        exit()

    return text_box.get('1.0', index2=END)
```

Comment: Lets us see your code and we might be able to understand better, normally windows are not created minimized.

Comment: Windows always start in their non-minimized state. You have to explicitly minimize them. Can you provide a [mcve] to illustrate the problem.

Comment: This is now a completely different question than the one I answered.

Answer (score 1):

The [`window.focus_force()` method](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) does this:

> Force the input focus to the widget. This is impolite. It's better to wait for the window manager to give you the focus. See also `.grab_set_global()` below.

Sometimes if this doesn't work, you can manually force it like so:

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.after(2000, window.focus_force)
window.mainloop()
```

Sometimes you will have [issues on Macs which can require some additional finagling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1892339/) but this should work fine elsewhere (OP has not specified any information about environment).

Comment: @BryanOakley good point. It takes a callback and I am used to wanting to pass it parameters so I use lambda to do so. In this case it is not needed since no params. Edited answer

Comment: forgive me master! I think I know why the problem appeared, and it's because I used withdraw and deiconify. but now I have yet another problem, how can I both use withdraw and when needed deiconify, open the window cenetered and make it appear on screen? for some reason if I make it appear on screen like you did, it is not opened centered... (earlier it did)

Comment: @Lidor try https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867710/ and also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17354686/