# How to specify where a Tkinter window opens?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How can I tell a Tkinter window where to open, based on screen dimensions? I would like it to open in the middle.

Comment: [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10018670/1217270)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This answer is based on [Rachel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14910894/839601). Her code did not work originally, but with some tweaking I was able to fix the mistakes.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk() # create a Tk root window

w = 800 # width for the Tk root
h = 650 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

# set the dimensions of the screen 
# and where it is placed
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

root.mainloop() # starts the mainloop
```

Answer (score 45):

Try this

```
import tkinter as tk


def center_window(width=300, height=200):
    # get screen width and height
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    # calculate position x and y coordinates
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))


root = tk.Tk()
center_window(500, 400)
root.mainloop()
```

[Source](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/66181/center-a-tkinter-window)

Comment: or refer to http://eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Center%20window.html for an alternative method

Comment: for maximum usefulness, you might want to fix your indentation.

Comment: @RachelGallen: do you realize that code is for a completely different toolkit? You can't use pyqt to center a tkinter window.

Comment: @BryanOakley i offered an alternative solution. besides he said he's working in python so why not?

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks for the help... but you should test your code before answering. Once you had given me the basic idea though, I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @RachelGallen upvote for helping me :) But... it is really easy to [install Python 2.7.3 for Windows](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.msi) Upvote granted.

Comment: Works fine for me with python 2.6 on windows 7

Comment: There is even better centering function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018670/3015186) which takes into account the titlebar height of the window (and the window frame width).

Answer (score 31):

```
root.geometry('250x150+0+0')
```

The first two parameters are the width and height of the window. The last two parameters are x and y screen coordinates. You can specify the required x and y coordinates

Comment: Great general solution to the problem that allows the user more flexibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you would like the window to be centered, this type of function may help you:

```
def center_window(size, window) :
    window_width = size[0] #Fetches the width you gave as arg. Alternatively window.winfo_width can be used if width is not to be fixed by you.
    window_height = size[1] #Fetches the height you gave as arg. Alternatively window.winfo_height can be used if height is not to be fixed by you.
    window_x = int((window.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (window_width / 2)) #Calculates the x for the window to be in the centre
    window_y = int((window.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (window_height / 2)) #Calculates the y for the window to be in the centre

    window_geometry = str(window_width) + 'x' + str(window_height) + '+' + str(window_x) + '+' + str(window_y) #Creates a geometric string argument
    window.geometry(window_geometry) #Sets the geometry accordingly.
    return
```

Here, the `window.winfo_screenwidth` function is used for getting the `width` of the device screen.
And the `window.winfo_screenheight` function is used for getting the `height` of the device screen.

Here you can call this function and pass a tuple with the (width, height) of the screen as the size.

You can customize the calculation as much as you want and it will change accordingly.

Comment: Simple difference from answers above, but works for different individual windows, which is nice

Answer (score 6):

`root.geometry('520x400+350+200')`

Explanation: ('width x height + X coordinate + Y coordinate')

Comment: What is the difference between you answer and the answer of @LordDraagon?

Answer (score 1):

A slight expansion to allow positioning around the screen

```
def position_window(width=300, height=200, xf = 0.5, yf = 0.5):
    
    # get screen width and height
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    # calculate position x and y coordinates
    x = (screen_width*xf) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height*yf) - (height/2)

    if x > screen_width-width:
        x  = screen_width-width
    if x < width:
        x = 0.0
    if y > screen_height-height:
        y  = screen_height-height*1.25
    if y < 0:
        y = 0
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use

```py
links_conf.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
```

It is possible to see that the window shows wherever you want and then changing its position, but hey! It's easy to use!