# choosing in which desktop Tkinter.Tk() opens the new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am on Linux/CentOS. I have multiple desktop.
When I launch this code,and in the meanwhile I change the desktop, the window opens in the current desktop and not in the original one (from which the code has been launched). Is there a way to tell Tk to stay in the desktop from which it has been launched?

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
time.sleep(5);Tk()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.. however you can specify where you would like the window to be placed by pixel value. 
See the following answers

[How to specify where a Tkinter window opens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens)

[How to center a window on the screen in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352918/how-to-center-a-window-on-the-screen-in-tkinter/10018670#10018670)