# Python Graphics library: How to set the x and y coordinates of the window?

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter

Currently, I am using [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/), a simple graphics library based on Tkinter:

I can create a graphics window:

```
from graphics import GraphWin 

winmap2 = GraphWin("Details", 200, 200)
winmap2.setBackground("Black")
```

How can I set the x, y coordinates of the window's position on my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphWin is in fact a tkinter `Canvas`.
Therefore you can use the same method than
[How to specify where a Tkinter window opens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens)

```
from graphics import GraphWin

winmap2 = GraphWin("Details", 200, 200)
winmap2.setBackground("Black")

x = 200
y = 100
winmap2.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (200, 200, x, y))
winmap2.mainloop()
```