# How to accurately save and restore the size and position of a tkinter main window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160293/how-to-remember-tkinter-window-position-in-python-3) I am trying to save and restore the position of the main window using tkinter. However, the problem I am having is that saving the geometry values (and any other method of obtaining the position) does not give accurate results.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from os.path import exists
import json

settings = {}
SettingFile = "mysettings.json"

class MyRoot(Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    wndCfg = { 'Size': [400, 400], 'Pos': [100, 100]}

    if 'MainWnd' in settings:
      wndCfg = settings['MainWnd']
    else:
      settings['MainWnd'] = wndCfg

    s = wndCfg['Size']
    p = wndCfg['Pos']

    self.geometry(f"{s[0]}x{s[1]}+{p[0]}+{p[1]}")

    
  def destroy(self):
    wndGeometry = self.geometry()
    parts = wndGeometry.split('+')
    wndPos = [int(parts[1]), int(parts[2])]
    parts = parts[0].split('x')
    wndSize = [int(parts[0]), int(parts[1])]

    # Various other options for getting the window position, x is correct, 
    # y is off by the height of the title bar
    pos0 = [self.winfo_x(), self.winfo_y()]
    pos1 = [self.winfo_rootx(), self.winfo_rooty()]

    settings['MainWnd']['Pos'] = wndPos # pos0 pos1
    settings['MainWnd']['Size'] = wndSize
    super().destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':

  if exists(SettingFile):
    with open(SettingFile, 'r') as cfgFile:
      settings = json.load(cfgFile)

  root = MyRoot()
  root.mainloop()

  with open(SettingFile, 'w') as cfgFile:
    json.dump(settings, cfgFile, indent=2)
```

When using the geometry() function and saving the values, it restores it slightly up and to the left of where it was previously. The other functions listed for obtaining the position give a correct value for x, but as stated in the comment, y is off by the height of the title bar.

I'm running this on Ubuntu (Pop_os!).

Is there a way to save an restore the window position accurately?

**Update**:
Following the links that Thingamabobs posted in the comments, I tried running the code that was posted as an answer in the [How do I calculate the rectangles of the window decoration / taskbar / titlebar in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78214938/how-do-i-calculate-the-rectangles-of-the-window-decoration-taskbar-titlebar) question. This code is supposed to calculate the rectangle areas for the title bar, working/client area of the window and the screen itself. The values I get are (0, 0, 1920, 65) (0, 65, 1920, 1015) (0, 0, 1920, 1080), giving a height of 65 for the title bar. Unfortunately this is wrong. I took a screenshot of my window and looked at it in an image editor and the title bar height is 37. In my original code, if I use pos0.x and pos0.y - 37, it works perfect.

I also ran the code for the accepted answer over at [How to get the height of a tkinter window title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742442/how-to-get-the-height-of-a-tkinter-window-title-bar) and it gives me a title bar height of 137.

patthoyts suggested delaying setting the geometry until after the first Map event had been posted. This didn't change anything from the original, however upon further testing I realized that the drift only happens if the window is moved.  If I run the app over and over, without moving the window, it will always reappear in the same position. It is only when I move the window to a new position that when I exit and restart, the window has moved up and to the left slightly.

I'm using the GNOME desktop.

Comment: Your code is working for me on Linux using a KDE desktop. The restored position is not drifting. I suspect the window manager might be affecting the placement. You are applying this quite early so you might try binding the first Map event and apply the geometry once the window has been mapped onto the display so this is after the window manager has placed the application window.

Comment: Your code works for me under Windows. Either try what patthoyts said or your window manager is giving wrong information by ignoring the window decoration. Since left shift probably be the borderwidth and height as you said the titlebar.

Comment: You might find useful [insight here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78214938/how-do-i-calculate-the-rectangles-of-the-window-decoration-taskbar-titlebar/78214939#78214939)