# How to activate tkinter window after destroying the previously one?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need the next `tkinter` window to become active automatically after destroying the previous one.

I'm working with `Python 3` in `Windows 10`.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

#Green button pressed
def passed():
    fails='0'
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'w')as TestResult:
        TestResult.write(fails)
    TestResult.close()
    root.destroy()

#Red button pressed
def failed():
    fails='1'
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'w')as TestResult:
        TestResult.write(fails)
    TestResult.close()
    root.destroy()

#First window
def PushHold(UUT):
    global root
    root = Tk()   
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda q:passed())
    TitleText="Push Button test"
    root.title(TitleText)
    root.geometry("460x160")
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    bottomframe = Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

    LABLE_TEXT = "Push and hold S1 on "+ UUT+" board.\n Click OK."
    label = Label( frame, text=LABLE_TEXT)
    label.config(font=("Arial", 22))
    label.pack( side = TOP)

    greenbutton = Button(frame, text="OK", bg="Green", fg="White", height=2 , width = 10 , command=lambda: passed())
    greenbutton.config(font=("Arial", 18))
    greenbutton.pack( side = LEFT, padx=140)
    root.mainloop()

#Second window
def Release(UUT):
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda q:passed())
    TitleText="Release Button test"
    root.title(TitleText)
    root.geometry("460x160")
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    bottomframe = Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

    LABLE_TEXT = "Release S1 on "+ UUT+" board.\n Click OK."
    label = Label( frame, text=LABLE_TEXT)
    label.config(font=("Arial", 22))
    label.pack( side = TOP)

    greenbutton = Button(frame, text="OK", bg="Green", fg="White", height=2 , width = 10 , command=lambda: passed())
    greenbutton.config(font=("Arial", 18))
    greenbutton.pack( side = LEFT, padx=140)
    root.mainloop()

#read results of the first window
def PushButton(UUT):
    PushHold(UUT)
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'r') as TestResult:
        str = list(TestResult)
        fails = int(str[0]) 
    TestResult.close()
    return fails

#read results of the second window
def ReleaseButton(UUT):
    Release(UUT)
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'r') as TestResult:
        str = list(TestResult)
        fails = int(str[0]) 
    TestResult.close()
    return fails

PushButton('UUT1')    #first window calling
ReleaseButton('UUT1')    #second window calling
```

The first window is working good, the second window appears, but not active. It is necessary to click on it to activate before pressing the button.

Trials to use `root.withdraw()` or `root.lift()` did not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system the second window takes focus without altering your code, so it is hard to tell. You could probably use `root.focus_force()` prior to calling `root.mainloop()`

Alternatively, you could spawn different windows from the same root, using `tk.Toplevel`.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

#Green button pressed
def passed():
    fails='0'
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'w')as TestResult:
        TestResult.write(fails)
    TestResult.close()
    root.destroy()

#Red button pressed
def failed():
    fails='1'
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'w')as TestResult:
        TestResult.write(fails)
    TestResult.close()
    root.destroy()

#First window
def PushHold(UUT):
    global root
    root = Tk()   
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda q:passed())
    TitleText="Push Button test"
    root.title(TitleText)
    root.geometry("460x160")
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    bottomframe = Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

    LABLE_TEXT = "Push and hold S1 on "+ UUT+" board.\n Click OK."
    label = Label( frame, text=LABLE_TEXT)
    label.config(font=("Arial", 22))
    label.pack( side = TOP)

    greenbutton = Button(frame, text="OK", bg="Green", fg="White", height=2 , width = 10 , command=lambda: passed())
    greenbutton.config(font=("Arial", 18))
    greenbutton.pack( side = LEFT, padx=140)
    root.focus_force()         #<-------------- Here ---------------------
    root.mainloop()

#Second window
def Release(UUT):
    global root
    root = Tk()
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda q:passed())
    TitleText="Release Button test"
    root.title(TitleText)
    root.geometry("460x160")
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    bottomframe = Frame(root)
    bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

    LABLE_TEXT = "Release S1 on "+ UUT+" board.\n Click OK."
    label = Label( frame, text=LABLE_TEXT)
    label.config(font=("Arial", 22))
    label.pack( side = TOP)

    greenbutton = Button(frame, text="OK", bg="Green", fg="White", height=2 , width = 10 , command=lambda: passed())
    greenbutton.config(font=("Arial", 18))
    greenbutton.pack( side = LEFT, padx=140)
    root.focus_force()         #<-------------- Here ---------------------
    root.mainloop()

#read results of the first window
def PushButton(UUT):
    PushHold(UUT)
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'r') as TestResult:
        str = list(TestResult)
        fails = int(str[0]) 
    TestResult.close()
    return fails

#read results of the second window
def ReleaseButton(UUT):
    Release(UUT)
    with open("ButtonPressed.txt",'r') as TestResult:
        str = list(TestResult)
        fails = int(str[0]) 
    TestResult.close()
    return fails

PushButton('UUT1')    #first window calling
ReleaseButton('UUT1')    #second window calling
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens