# Control location on screen where new windows open with graphics.py

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I have a python program that deploys a windows via `graphics.py`. The initial window opened by the `GraphWin` class opens in the top left corner of the screen. Subsequent calls to `GraphWin` cascade from the upper left to the lower right.

I'd like to control the placement of each window. (Example: Have all the windows open in a grid-layout so I can create a dashboard.)

Answer (score 1):

`graphics.py` doesn't provide a way for you to control the location of instances of its `GraphWin` class. However the fact that it's built on top of Python's Tk GUI toolkit module named [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter) means that sometimes you can work around its limitations by looking at its source code to see how things operate internally.

For example, here's a snippet of code from the module (version 5.0) showing the beginning of `GraphWin` class' definition from the `graphics.py` file:

```
class GraphWin(tk.Canvas):

    """A GraphWin is a toplevel window for displaying graphics."""

    def __init__(self, title="Graphics Window",
                 width=200, height=200, autoflush=True):
        assert type(title) == type(""), "Title must be a string"
        master = tk.Toplevel(_root)
        master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=width, height=height,
                           highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
        self.master.title(title)
        self.pack()
        master.resizable(0,0)
        self.foreground = "black"
        self.items = []
        self.mouseX = None
        self.mouseY = None
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self._onClick)
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self._onKey)
        self.height = int(height)
        self.width = int(width)
        self.autoflush = autoflush
        self._mouseCallback = None
        self.trans = None
        self.closed = False
        master.lift()
        self.lastKey = ""
        if autoflush: _root.update()
```

As you can see it's derived from a [`tkinter.Canvas`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190510131423id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html) widget which has an attribute named `master` which is a [`tkinter.Toplevel`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429194251id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html) widget. It then initializes the `Canvas` base class and specifies the newly created `Toplevel` window as its parent.

The size and position of a `Toplevel` window can be controlled by calling its `geometry()` method as described in the linked documentation. This method expects to be passed a "geometry string" argument in a [certain format](https://web.archive.org/web/20190423044654id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html) (`'wxh±x±y'`).

This mean you can take advantage of how this implementation detail in order to put it anywhere you want it and as well as resize if desired.

Here's an example of doing that:

```
from graphics import *


def main():
    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)

    # Override size and position of the GraphWin.
    w, h = 300, 300  # Width and height.
    x, y = 500, 500  # Screen position.
    win.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
    c.draw(win)
    win.getMouse() # pause for click in window
    win.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My desktop while script is running:

[image: desktop]

Comment: Iggy: Doesn't this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such method in graphics.py right now.

Ref: The [Book](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf) and [webpage](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node3.html).

If you want to stick to using graphics.py, I suggest creating a dashboard by dividing a single window into different slots.

This option does exist in Tkinter library. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens) answer for more information on that.