# New window is offset from old window

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I'm having trouble when closing and opening new windows in python.  The new window is always offset from the old window.  As I'm using a small display for the project I need the position of the new window to be the same as the old window.

Here's what the first window looks like.

[image]

When the "login" button is clicked, the first window is deleted and a new window generated.  Notice the offset.

[image]

It's not a huge offset, but enough to cause problems in the small display.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button


def login_window(parent):

    def login():
        tp.destroy()
        parent.deiconify()

    tp = Toplevel()
    tp.title('Login Window')
    tp.geometry('480x320')
    tp.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', parent.quit)

    Button(tp, text='Login', command=login).pack()


def main_window():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Main Window')
    root.geometry('480x320')
    root.withdraw()

    login_window(root)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_window()
```

I haven't been able to google a fix for this.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify where a Tkinter window opens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910858/how-to-specify-where-a-tkinter-window-opens)

Comment: It's a somewhat common feature across windowing systems, on many operating systems.

Comment: Do you want to programmatically open a window in a particular position on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change in the `root.geometry` from `root.geometry('widthxheight')` to `root.geometry("widthxheight+position_x+position_y")`for example `root.geometry("480x320+0+0")`.