# How to get the size of tk.Toplevel widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am creating a pop-up window using **Tkinter**.

```
def show_warning(self, msg):
    self.warning = tk.Toplevel()
    self.centrify_widget(self.warning)
    self.warning.title('Warning!')
    self.warn.resizable(0, 0)
    self.warnFr = ttk.Frame(self.warning, borderwidth=2, relief='groove')
    self.warnFr.grid()
    ttk.Label(self.warnFr, font='TkDefaultFont 11', text=msg).grid()
    ttk.Button(self.warnFr, text='OK', command=self.warning.destroy).grid()
```

I want this pop-up window to appear *centrified* according to the application position.

```
def centrify_widget(self, widget):
    rwidth = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    rheight = self.winfo_screenheight()
    x, y = (rwidth/2) - (widget.width/2), (rheight/2) - (widget.height/2)
    widget.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (widget.width, widget.height, x, y))
```

The code above won't work because `tk.Toplevel` does not have *width* or *height* attributes.

So, how do I *centrify* the pop-up window when I do not know its **height** and **width**?

I can't hardcode it because my `show_warning` function accepts `msg` of different length and if I explicitly give **height** and **width** the window geometry will be broken like below.

[image]

Comment: have you checked `widget.winfo_height()` and `widget.winfo_width()`?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3352918/7432

Comment: Thing is, Toplevel window returns the resolution of my monitor 1600x900 but appears to be small enough to contain the message cause this is the default behaviour. If I attempt to set it via geometry the pop-up window will become 1600x900 in size.

Comment: actually the example in the answer link above works, hmm