# Display An Image While Python GUI is Loading

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a working GUI interface using Tkinter, Python. It takes a minuet or two to load the GUI, my question is the following:

**Is there away to display an image while python is performing the load on the GUI?**

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: You could potentially spawn a new TopLevel which has an image on it. I have to wonder why your GUI takes so long to load though.

Comment: @scotty3785, it takes about 10 seconds to display the GUI, however, when I use pyinstaller to package the GUI and use it for another machine "I am using Windows" which doesn't have python install, it takes a minuet or so to display it , any idea?

Comment: Just display another, simpler UI (with just the image) before starting to load the real UI?

Comment: Did that, thanks, now how to not include the tool bar as I want only the image ?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments you can use a TopLevel to display another window.
You can use `<NameOfYourTopLevel>.overrideredirect(1)` to hide the window frame.

You might also consider using `.after_idle(<callback>)` to close the window once the GUI has completed loading.

Here is more complete example. I haven't been able to replicate the large delay in drawing the GUI so have simulated this with `self.after(5000,self.splash.destroy)`. You should be able to replace this with `self.after_idle(self.splash.destroy)`

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        self.splash = Splash(root)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        tk.Label(self,text="MainFrame").grid()
        self.after(5000,self.splash.destroy)

class Splash(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        tk.Label(self,text="Show Image here").grid()
        self.overrideredirect(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    App(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352918/how-to-center-a-window-on-the-screen-in-tkinter) will tell you how to centre the window in your screen.

Comment: what kind of argument is <callback>?

Comment: It is the handle/name of a function.

Comment: I haven't test this on my code because I am away from computer but thanks so much for the help, will tell how it turned out to be. Vote up for you my friend!