# What is 'tk::placeWindow' and how can it center the window on my screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to find a way to center the window of a simple counter I made using Tkinter. Trying to find another way than using geometry I came across:

```
window.eval('tk::placeWindow . center')
```

But I don't know why this works and also I cant find it in the documentation. Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center a window on the screen in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352918/how-to-center-a-window-on-the-screen-in-tkinter)

Comment: The `tk::placeWindow` command is basically just calling the underlying C/Tk code, as you can see here: https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/tk.tcl#L72

Comment: Im new to python and its really confusing... Why can I put it inside eval?

Comment: It's not like a normal python eval - the eval you are calling is a method of the `window` Tk class, and as such its custom behavior is to pass on whatever you put there to the underlying `Tcl/Tk` engine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below executes code that is written in tcl and calls a tcl procedure. There are [quite a few of them](https://svn.python.org/projects/external/tk-8.6.3.x/library/tclIndex), but they mostly used for internal procedures and rarely useful.

```
window.eval('tk::placeWindow . center')
```

The [placeWindow](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/master/library/tk.tcl#L72) procedure can be found here and does nothing that you couldn't do with python. They are most likely for maintainers that are used to tcl.