# How do I efficiently center a window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem where when I create a window in Tkinter, it is offset a bit to the side instead of centered. I was wondering if there was some way to center the window without using too many lines of code. I've tried using `.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')`, but it just sets the top left edge of the window to the center. I've also tried calculating the size of the window and placing it with .geometry().
Here I have a button that creates a window when clicked:

```
from Tkinter import *

button = Button(lambda:newWind(title))

#function being called

def newWind(bPressed):
    newApp = tk.Tk()
    newApp.title(bPressed)
    newApp.geometry('1920x1080')
```

The window is offset by about 10 pixels when created. Any easy and short way I can fix this?

Comment: OP tried that way.

Comment: If `tk::PlaceWindow` does not work, then calculate the required `(x, y)` yourself and it is not hard.

Comment: @acw1668 if it is not hard, could you give me the coordinates? also, how do I implement (x, y) to place the window?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the PlaceWindow method again correctly. I think it will place a tkinter window at the center of the screen where you can pass the top level window as an argument and add it into the center.

```
newApp.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
```

Comment: How would I exactly be using the method incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

If `.eval("tk::PlaceWindow . center")` does not work, you can calculate the required position `(x, y)` based on the window and screen size and use `.geometry()` to place the window at the calculated position:

```py
def center_window(win):
    # make sure window is updated
    win.update()
    # get the screen resolution
    scr_width, scr_height = win.winfo_screenwidth(), win.winfo_screenheight()
    # get the window resolution
    border_width = win.winfo_rootx() - win.winfo_x()
    title_height = win.winfo_rooty() - win.winfo_y()
    win_width = win.winfo_width() + border_width + border_width
    win_height = win.winfo_height() + title_height + border_width
    # calculate the position
    x = (scr_width - win_width) // 2
    y = (scr_height - win_height) // 2
    # place the window at the calculated position
    win.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

def newWind(bPressed):
    newApp = tk.Tk()
    newApp.title(bPressed)
    newApp.geometry('1920x1080')
    # center the window
    center_window(newApp)
```

Note that it is better to use `tk.Toplevel` instead of `tk.Tk` for windows other than the root/main window.

Comment: hmm. `center_win` seems to be overwriting the `newApp.geometry('1920x1080')` or something. regardless, the window is still slightly off center.

Comment: Only position is used in `.geometry()` inside `center_window()`, so it won't overwrite the window size.  The offset may be caused by that the window size may not include the height of the title bar.

Comment: the window is still offset on the x-axis. should i tweak the width of the window as well to fix that?

Comment: The horizontal offset is due to the width of the window border.  You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018670/5317403) to calculate the size of the window border and the title bar.