# Centering Turtle Window

Tags: python, python-turtle

So I am using a chromebook and I am trying to centre the window in turtle but it will not centre. This is my code:
main.py

```
# Imports
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player
from car_manager import CarManager
from scoreboard import Scoreboard

# Screen Setup

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600, startx=None, starty=None)
screen.tracer(0)

# Class Setup

turtle_player = Player()

# Key Presses

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(turtle_player.forwards, "Up")

# Main loop

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
time.sleep(0.1)
screen.update()
```

player.py

```
from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280

class Player(Turtle):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
self.penup()
self.goto(STARTING_POSITION)
self.seth(90)

    def forwards(self):
        self.forward(10)
```

I have tried to set the `start_x` and `start_y` to `None` but it didn't work

[The Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0VVd.png)

I want to centre it by default in the middle of the screen

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "center the window".  Do you mean to center it on your desktop?  That's exactly what it does for me on Linux.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*center the window*"?

Comment: perhaps include a screenshot of where the window is appearing on the screen, and give more information about your screen resolution.  Do you also have an external monitor connected? 
  The code provided should be automatically centering the window on the screen and putting the turtle at the bottom center.

Comment: When you say, "I am using a chromebook", I'm guessing you're not running Python on the Chromebook but rather running Python with turtle on a website like Repl.it where the turtle window is opening within a web page.  Is that correct, or are you running Python directly on the Chromebook under Linux?

Comment: Im running it on the linux dev options

Comment: And I mean like centering it on the screen

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a pure turtle solution, so I introduce low-level calls to tkinter. I based this off of [@HonestAbe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352918/how-to-center-a-window-on-the-screen-in-tkinter). Look at his answer for a detailed explanation. Here is the function:

```
def center():
    root = turtle.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
    root.update_idletasks()
    width = root.winfo_width()
    frame_width = root.winfo_rootx() - root.winfo_x()
    window_width = width + 2 * frame_width
    height = root.winfo_height()
    titlebar_height = root.winfo_rooty() - root.winfo_y()
    window_height = height + titlebar_height + frame_width
    x = root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - window_width // 2
    y = root.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - window_height // 2
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
```

Here is an example:

```py
import turtle


def center():
    root = turtle.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
    root.update_idletasks()
    width = root.winfo_width()
    frame_width = root.winfo_rootx() - root.winfo_x()
    window_width = width + 2 * frame_width
    height = root.winfo_height()
    titlebar_height = root.winfo_rooty() - root.winfo_y()
    window_height = height + titlebar_height + frame_width
    x = root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - window_width // 2
    y = root.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - window_height // 2
    root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
    
    
center()
turtle.mainloop()
```